# What is the correct HTTP status code to send when a site is down for maintenance?

Tags: http, http-response-codes

Is there a HTTP status code to tell Google (and others) to *go away, index me again later*?

Basically, one that semantically tells clients that the site is down for maintenance?

The ones I have considered are

```
304 => Not modified
307 => Temporary redirect
410 => Gone
503 => Service Unavailable
```

I'm leaning towards the last one, but was just curious as to which one was *proper* choice.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

[HTTP 503 - Service Unavailable](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html) would be the most appropriate.

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay.

This post on the Google Webmaster Central Forum is also relevant:

- [Can I restrict Google from crawling my site on a specific day of the week?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=07309f6d7a300cdc&hl=en)

> Yes - a 503 is the correct server response for "We're closed".  If you substitute a normal HTML page saying "We're closed" and serve a 200 it's very likely to get indexed by Google.
>
> If you give the Googlebot a 503, it will just go away and come back later without indexing what you give it.

---

**UPDATE:**

As for the php implementation, you may be interested in checking out the following article:

- [The holding page and the 503 status code](http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/503-holding-page/)

Also notice the [`retry-after`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.3) header, where you can specify after how many seconds another request should be re-attempted.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer working with http2 - when I send a 503 with the maintenance page, Chrome shows an ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. If I send a 200, everything is fine

Comment: @Xosofox Today I tested HTTP 503 serving a customized error page from Apache 2.4 and it worked well in all browsers.

 **MacOS 11 Big Sur** ✅ Safari 16.4.1  ✅ Chrome 113.0.5672.92 ✅ Firefox ✅ 113.0.1.

 **iOS 15.7.5**: ✅ Mobile Safari 15.6.

 **ChromeOS 113**.0.5672.114: ✅ Chrome (same version as OS).

 **Windows 10**: ✅ Edge 113.0.1774.42.

Comment: Note: I did this with a maintenance `.htaccess` with a `RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]` to rewrites all requests (`RewriteCond` It is NOT the error document itself or any of the special service URLs which continue to run independent from main CMS) serving a custom error document for the HTTP 503 status code with `ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html`.

Answer (score 9):

From http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40132

503 (Service unavailable)    The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider the 503 to be most appropriate, since the 5xx-group is meant for server errors in general.

Answer (score 4):

503 Service Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

503 Service Unavailable

as 5XX series belongs to server-side issues